# Make smaller font size for title

Tags: titles, fontsize, overleaf

I have this following latex code for my project latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{3 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}

\title{Snort Based Intrusion Detection ft.  ML Models}  
\author{Cicada3301}                             % Author
\date{\today}                                           % Date

\makeatletter
\let\thetitle\@title
\let\theauthor\@authaor
\let\thedate\@date
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\theauthor}
\lhead{\thetitle}
\cfoot{\thepage}

\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \vspace*{-4.5 cm}
    \includegraphics[scale = 0.4]{K.png}\\[0.2 cm]  % University Logo
    \textsc{ \newline\newline MIT}\\[0.8 cm]
    \textsc{\Large CS111}\\[1 cm]   
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[0.4 cm]
    { \huge \bfseries \thetitle}\\
    \rule{\linewidth}{0.2 mm} \\[1.5 cm]
        \textsc{\Large \textbf{Group - CICADA3301}}\\[0.5 cm]   
    
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{flushleft} \large
            \emph{Professor:}\\
            Dr. XYZ\\
            Department of Computer Science\
            \end{flushleft}
            \end{minipage}~
            \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
            
            \begin{flushright} \large
            \emph{Members} \\
            A G 
            
            Roll-3\\
            \vspace{1cm}
            S S Roll-2\\
        \end{flushright}
        
    \end{minipage}\\[2 cm]


\end{titlepage}

\newpage



\end{document}
```

The problem here is that the title is too big and it is taking 2 lines.

[image]

But I want to make the title small so that it fits into a single line. How can I do this in overleaf? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You could replace `\huge` with `\Large`.

Comment: @user187803 Thanks................. :)

Comment: As can be seen in the image it is not a good idea to use `\textsc{\Large CS111}\\[1 cm]` as this ends up using the wrong line spacing. I would not use those `\\[...]` or `\newline` either. Write each of the lines with blank lines in bewteen, written as `{\huge ... \par}` note the `\par` here to get the proper line spacing. If space is needed between these one-line paragraphs I'd just add some `\vspace{length}` between them.

Comment: urelated but avoid `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` unless your latex is very old, just delete this. `[uf8]` is the default anyway, Are you sure you want `\hbadness=10000` ??? that means "no matter how bad the output is, make no warning" most people who use TeX care enough about the output to get at least some warnings when TeX can not achieve a reasonable result.